# Downgrading a package and dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, downgrade

I want to downgrade libcairo2 to the version from Precise (I'm running Quantal). I've added the precise source to my sources.list and can do 'apt-get install libcairo2=', but it's going to remove some packages that I definitely want to keep, specifically xubuntu-desktop.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

No, downgrading is not supported.

Comment: What does `apt-get install {package}={VERSION}` do?

Comment: According to the apt-get man page, specifying the version can/does downgrade a package. I would just love for it to downgrade the dependencies as well. Instead it wants to remove them. Having said that, when I added the precise source, I didn't add all the universe and multiverse. Could that be why it wouldn't downgrade dependencies? Because it couldn't find them?

Comment: @JustinMiller, you will have to manually specify that all of the other packages need downgraded, but such a configuration is not supported, and very likely to break your system.